# Attaching CSV file to reply for Microsoft Bot Framework for Teams

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am creating a bot that needs to return a csv file from an azure storage blob as a response (i.e. give me a listing of all users and email addresses). When I run the request in the bot framework emulator it works great, but when trying in teams (which will be used for the chatbot) I get the following error.

> Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest' at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync(String
>   conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, Dictionary2
>   customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.ReplyToActivityAsync(IConversations
>   operations, String conversationId, String activityId, Activity
>   activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.SendActivitiesAsync(ITurnContext
>   turnContext, Activity[] activities, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<g__SendActivitiesThroughAdapter|1>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.SendActivityAsync(IActivity
>   activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken).

Here is the part where I an attaching the file to the message.

```
var message = MessageFactory.Text(noOfUsersFoundText, noOfUsersFound, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment
{
    Name = fileName,
    ContentType = "text/csv",
    ContentUrl = fileUrl
});
await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(message, cancellationToken);
```

Has any one gotten this to work?

UPDATE: This is from the App Studio Editor in teams.

[image]

Comment: Could you please make sure if you have allowed "supportFiles" to true for your Bot?

Comment: Are you sure the "fileUrl" has correct value?

Comment: fileUrl is set to the link for the file in Azure, I have supportFiles set on App Studio app for teams. I've read that there is a place to set it in the manifest, but my program doesn't have a manifest file.

Comment: Also in Visual Studio 2019, I can't find a place to add the application manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok from what I read, only image files can be used as attachments.  So I went with sending a hero card to the url.  And that seems to work.